# Iphone: Virtual keyboard don´t hide after taping/clicking on "Go" Button

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

I´ve got a form with an input field and a submit button. Nothing fancy here...

On the iPhone (iPhone 4S, iOS 5.1) i use the virtual keyboard to fill the input field and when i click/tap on the Go Button of the keyboard the form is submitted. But the virtual keyboard don´t hide after the submit.

If i use the submit button of the form the keyboard disappear. This problem exist only when i click the Go Button of the keyboard

Are there any javascript events i should check? Or do you have a hint for me?

Btw: In other forms with the same structure this problem do not exist.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this code in click event to dismiss virtual keyboard

`document.activeElement.blur();`

Comment: you mean submit event, I suppose?

Comment: Yes, if you run this code onsubmit then the keyboard should disappear :)